# How to get month name abbr instead of month number in Hive

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I want month name instead of month number from a Date passed in HIVE

I am doing

```
select Month(date_field) from <tablename>;
```

this gives me a month number. How to get month names ??

Comment: how does your date_field look like? also which version of Hive are you using?

Answer (score 12):

Use `MMM` with [`date_format`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) function.

```
date_format(date_field,'MMM')
```

To get the full month name, use

```
date_format(date_field,'MMMMM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below builtin function to get the month in short form.
select  from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp ("28/01/2017 00:00:00",'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'MMM')